# How make androidx.media3.ui.DefaultTimeBar as rounded corner in andriod

Tags: android

I have androidx.media3.ui.DefaultTimeBar and i want to show this progress bar with rounded corner. i tried a lot to make its corner ans rounded but i did not find the soultion for this. My code is given below.

```
<androidx.media3.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_30dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/window_close"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/exo_player_fwd_ten_sec"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/exo_playback_speed"
            app:buffered_color="@android:color/white"
            app:played_color="@android:color/black"
            app:scrubber_color="@android:color/black"
            app:unplayed_color="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/seekbar_rounded_corner"
            app:scrubber_drawable="@drawable/thumb"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
```

seekbar_rounded_corner.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" /> <!-- Adjust the radius to control the roundness of the corners -->
            <solid android:color="#DDDDDD" /> <!-- Background color for the time bar -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please guide me to make rounded corner of DefaultTimeBar

Answer (score 0):

1 create a rounded shape
res/drawable/seekbar_rounded_corner.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" /> <!-- Adjust the radius to control the roundness of the corners -->
    <solid android:color="#DDDDDD" /> <!-- Background color for the time bar -->
</shape>
```

2 remove the background from the xml media object

3 set the shape background in your activity / fragment

```
DefaultTimeBar timeBar = findViewById(R.id.exo_progress);
Drawable roundedCornerDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.seekbar_rounded_corner);
timeBar.setBackground(roundedCornerDrawable);
```